# H5PY IOError: Unable to open file (File signature not found)

Tags: python, file, h5py, ioerror

I'm having problems opening .h5 files.

I've googled around and messed about with keras but still no luck.

Here's my code :-

and this is giving me an error of :-

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import h5py

""" Reading Data from Files """

plt.close('all')

#File No.
Q = str(4)

""" Position """
with h5py.File('Data_No'+Q+'/Position_No'+Q+'.h5', 'r') as hf:
    Position = hf['Position_Data'][:]
```

And its giving an error which i have no idea whats going wrong :-

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/media/gerwyn/Gerwyns_Files/Work/PLF/Animation.py", line 20, in
>
> with h5py.File('Data_No'+Q+'/Position_No'+Q+'.h5', 'r') as hf:
>
> File "/home/gerwyn/Documents/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
>
> packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 271, in **init**
>
> fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
>
> File "/home/gerwyn/Documents/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-
>
> packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 101, in make_fid
>
> fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
>
> File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>
> File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>
> File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 78, in h5py.h5f.open
>
> IOError: Unable to open file (File signature not found)

Can someone please help me in my little predicament ?

Thanks :D

Comment: Are you sure that file is a `HDF5` file?  Can you check it with a OS level command (e.g. `h5dump`)?

Comment: The h5 file was working a month ago, how would you use h5dump?

Comment: `h5dump` is part of a useful set of [command line tools for HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html). Use `h5dump -n <file>` to list all the groups and datasets in the file. If you can't open it / see the contents with that, then it's probably an issue with the file itself, not an IO issue related to python.

Comment: thanks, it simply says cant open file, although i am absolutely sure i could open it a month ago. Whats happened?