# How do I download h5dump? (h5dump: command not found)

Tags: hdf5

I'm getting an IOerror trying to open a HDF5 file, so I should use H5dump to check the file (according to: [H5PY IOError: Unable to open file (File signature not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974600/h5py-ioerror-unable-to-open-file-file-signature-not-found?rq=1)). However, I have no clue what to download to obtain usage of the h5dump command.

I have already downloaded and built the binary distribution for centOS (https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/) but that did not help. I have found the doc pages (https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Dump). Every command is meticulously described, including h5dump, but they have not included a single download link for reasons incomprehensible for my tiny brain.

I've opened the HDF5 file with the HDFViewer tool, if thats anything. How do I get `h5dump`?

Comment: I am on macOS Mojave.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic as it has nothing to do with programming. You may want to try https://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Speaking from experience, `h5dump` is a handy tool when writing a program that reads a HDF5 file. Its a quick way to discover the schema and related datasets when first learning about HDF5.

Answer (score 2):

The utilities are included in the gzipped tarball (`hdf5-1.10.5-linux-centos7-x86_64-shared.tar.gz`) found at the link below. Look under **Pre-built Binary Distributions**:

[DOWNLOAD HDF5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdf5/)

Once you extract the files, you will have a `bin` directory. That's where you will find `h5dump` and many other utilities. Good luck.

Comment: @Thomas Weller, Check the **DOWNLOAD HDF5** link above. It will take you the the HDF Group page with links  to download Pre-built Binary Distributions. After you install, you will find all of the utilities (including `h5dump`) in `C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.6\bin` (or similar pathname)

Comment: Sorry, in hindsight I don't know how I could miss all these win7 and win10 releases.

Answer (score 1):

On an ubuntu-flavour linux box you can type

```
sudo apt-get install hdf5-tools
```

I think on a mac you can also do

```
brew install hdf5
```

this should give you `h5dump`